# Admin Custom Plugin List Files in admin Table

Tags: plugins, admin, media-library, wp-list-table, wp-filesystem

I'm building a plugin that works only in admin.

I've a page where I need a list of files, users can only download or delete the file.

I've this questions:

1. I don't know what is better to list the files in a specific folder or files saved in media library associated a specific category?
2. How can I get files list from a specific folder?
3. How can I get files list form a specific media library category?
4. How can I put and show the list in a WP admin list standard table?

Where can I find some code examples?

Regards.

Alex

Comment: can you split those up so that there is one question per question? We have a 1 question per question policy. As this isn't a discussion forum, the only way to provide an answer for this question is to thoroughly answer all 4 questions correctly at the same time. This significantly reduces the chances of an answer. Also question 2 isn't a WP question but a general PHP filesystem question that could be asked on stackoverflow. Question 1 may not have a correct answer. Question 4 already has already been asked 
 elsewhere on the site ( look up custom admin table lists )

Comment: Ah ok, sorry. The question was how to put a file list in a WP admin standard table.
I was only courius what was better "getting the list from the file system or from the wordpress media library.

Comment: Oh it's not that there were problems with your questions, it's just that you bundled them all together. Instead of clicking ask question once and smushing them all into a single question, you should have clicked ask question 4 times, once for each question you wanted to ask. 1 question per question. Use the `Edit` link to narrow it down to just 1 question, then ask the other 3 questions independently. You'll get longer, better answers, more reputation points, and more attention

Comment: Ah ok... no prob. Next time I'll try to do it better ;) 
It's my first time ^_^